# My game of Master mind keeps adding after every loop

Tags: java

The program works fine but when it loops which is at the begginging where the comment loop is. The counter adds it instead of reseting after every loop. Example: Turn 1: You have 1 correct in the right spot. Then if i enter in the same numbers again on Turn 2 i would get: You have 2 correct in the right spot. And it would keep adding on from there.

```
 class Mastermind 
        {
            public static void main (String[] args)
            {
                //Welcome
                System.out.println ("Welcome to Matthew's game of Mastermind!");
                //Variable
                int Tally;
                int guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4;
                Scanner Guess = new Scanner (System.in);
                int[] Secret_code = Mystery();
                int[] Gameboard = Gameboard (Secret_code);
                int resultCount = Comparing (Secret_code, Gameboard);
                int resultCount2 = Comparing2 (Secret_code, Gameboard);
                //Loop
                 for (Tally = 0; Tally <10; Tally++){
                   //User Input
             System.out.println ("What is the number one peg in my code?");
             guess1 = Guess.nextInt();
             System.out.println ("What is the number two peg in my code?");
             guess2 = Guess.nextInt();
             System.out.println ("What is the number three peg in my code?");
             guess3 = Guess.nextInt();
             System.out.println ("What is the number four peg in my code?");
             guess4 = Guess.nextInt();
             //Array for guess's
             Gameboard = new int [4];
             Gameboard[0] = guess1;
             Gameboard[1] = guess2;
             Gameboard[2] = guess3;
             Gameboard[3] = guess4;
             //result Count 
             for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             if (Gameboard[i] == Secret_code[i])
              resultCount++;
            }
           System.out.println("You got " + resultCount + " correct in the right spot."); 
           //Result Count 2
           int i = 0;
              for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
                if (Gameboard[e] == Secret_code[i])
                 resultCount2++;
                }
                System.out.println ("You got " + resultCount2 + " correct but in the wrong spot");
                    if (Secret_code[0] == Gameboard[0] && Secret_code[1] == Gameboard[1] && Secret_code[2] == Gameboard[2] && Secret_code[3] == Gameboard[3]){
                    break;
                }
                if (Tally > 10){
                    System.out.println ("You have exceeded your 10 tries. You lose. Please play again.");
                    break;
                }
        }
                //Goodbye
                System.out.println ("Thank you for playing.");            
                //Winner
                if (Gameboard[0] == Secret_code[0] && Gameboard[1] == Secret_code[1] && Gameboard[2] == Secret_code[2] && Gameboard[3] == Secret_code[3])
                System.out.println ("You have won this game of Mastermind!");
            }


            public static int[] Mystery () {

                //Random
                int secretcode = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
                int secretcode1 = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
                int secretcode2 = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
                int secretcode3 = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;

               //Secretcode print
               //System.out.println (secretcode);      Used this for testing to make sure the codes were being outputted correctly.
               //System.out.println (secretcode1);
               //System.out.println (secretcode2);
               //System.out.println (secretcode3);

               //Array
               int [] Secret_code;
               Secret_code = new int [4];
               Secret_code[0] = secretcode;
               Secret_code[1] = secretcode1;
               Secret_code[2] = secretcode2;
               Secret_code[3] = secretcode3;

                return Secret_code;
        }
            public static int[] Gameboard (int[] Secret_code) {
            //Variable Declaration
            int guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4;
            Scanner Guess = new Scanner (System.in);

            //User Guess's
             System.out.println ("What is the number one peg in my code?");
             guess1 = Guess.nextInt();
             System.out.println ("What is the number two peg in my code?");
             guess2 = Guess.nextInt();
             System.out.println ("What is the number three peg in my code?");
             guess3 = Guess.nextInt();
             System.out.println ("What is the number four peg in my code?");
             guess4 = Guess.nextInt();

             //Array
             int [] Gameboard;
             Gameboard = new int [4];
             Gameboard[0] = guess1;                             //This puts the user's guess's into an array which just makes it easier to compare with the secret code's array
             Gameboard[1] = guess2;
             Gameboard[2] = guess3;
             Gameboard[3] = guess4;

             return Gameboard;
    }
            public static int Comparing (int[] Secret_code, int[] Gameboard){
             int resultCount = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             if (Gameboard[i] == Secret_code[i])
              resultCount++;
            }
    System.out.println("You got " + resultCount + " correct in the right spot."); 
    return resultCount;
    }
    public static int Comparing2 (int[] Secret_code, int[] Gameboard){
              int resultCount2 = 0;
              int i = 0;
              for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
                if (Gameboard[e] == Secret_code[i])
                 resultCount2++;
                }
                System.out.println ("You got " + resultCount2 + " correct but in the wrong spot");
                return resultCount2;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `resultCount` is never reset. It should be set to 0 at the beginning of the for loop. Same for `resultCount2`

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate coding. you ask the user for input in main() and also in Gameboard() method. you set resultCount = Comparing() (where you print the result) and also again in main() where you print the result a 2nd time.

in the loop, you should call the Comparing methods (where the counter gets reset and the printing is done) instead of calculation:

```
//result Count
resultCount = Comparing (Secret_code, Gameboard);
//Result Count 2
resultCount2 = Comparing2 (Secret_code, Gameboard);
```